# Recorrer y eliminar todos los ceros de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo la lista

```
a = [1,2,0,3,0]
```

Y necesito eliminar los ceros de modo que la lista para tener esto

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: una opcion seria rrecorrer tu array y evaluar cada uno de los elementos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En general, eliminar cosas de una estructura de datos mientras se recorre la estructura es peligroso. Es el equivalente de serrar una rama de un árbol mientras estás sentado en ella :-)

La estrategia típica es hacer una función que, en lugar de elminar elementos, cree una nueva lista vacía y le vaya añadiendo elementos de la otra, saltándose los que querrías eliminar, para finalmente retornar la nueva lista.

Usando esta idea:

```py
def elimina_ceros(original):
    nueva = []
    for dato in original:
        if dato != 0:
            nueva.append(dato)
    return nueva


a = [1,2,0,3,0]
a = elimina_ceros(a)
```

Y si haces uso de la sintaxis *list comprehension* puedes ahorrarte la función anterior y la cosa queda tan simple como:

```py
>>> a = [1,2,0,3,0]
>>> a = [elemento for elemento in a if elemento !=0]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Ten en cuenta que, tanto en el caso de la función como en el dela *list comprehension* no estamos quitando nada de la lista original, sino creando una nueva. No obstante, al asignar el resultado a la misma variable `a`, la lista original quedará "sin nombre" y el recolector de basura de python la eliminará de memoria.

**Actualización** El usuario sugirió en un comentario el utilizar `a.remove(0)` como parte de un bucle `for` en que se detectan ceros. Este enfoque no funciona bien como puede verse en el siguiente ejemplo:

```py
a = [1,0,2,0,0,3,4,0]
for i in a:
    if i==0:
        a.remove(0)
    print(a)          # Incluyo este print para ver cosas raras
```

La salida es:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

Y el valor final de `a` es `[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]` en el que como vemos no se han eliminado todos los ceros. Observa en concreto las salidas en la tercera, cuarta y quinta iteraciones del bucle. ¡Son iguales!

A esto precisamente me refería cuando decía que no es seguro eliminar elementos mientras se itera por ellos. El `for` construye un iterador a partir de la lista inicial, si esa lista se cambia dentro del `for` los resultados son imprevisibles.

Pero esa idea me ha sugerido otra aún más fea :-) Se trata de invocar repetidamente a `a.remove(0)` hasta que no queden más ceros. Pero en este caso sin usar un iterador, sino simplemente "insistiendo" en un bucle infinito, hasta obtener la excepción `ValueError` que se produce cuando intentemos eliminar un cero y ya no hay más.

El (horrible) código es éste. Lo pongo sólo como curiosidad. No lo intenten en sus casas:

```py
a = [1,0,2,0,0,3,4,0]
while True:
   try:
     a.remove(0)
   except ValueError:
     break
```

Comment: "Es el equivalente de serrar una rama de un árbol mientras estás sentado en ella :-)"

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido esta, pero a lo mejor es como tu dices de serrar la rama mientras estoy sentado.
`for i in a:
 if i == 0:
  a.remove(0)`

Comment: @MiguelNavaza Mira mi actualización

Comment: He utilizado  sintaxis list comprehension. Funciona a la perfección. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@abulafia ya explica correctamente el problema de modificar la longitud de un iterable (tanto eliminar como agregar items) a la que se itera sobre ella.

Generalmente esto se hace creando una nueva lista como se ha explicado, pero puede darse el caso en la que esto tiene un coste importante (no suele ser un problema ya que las listas solo almacenan referencias), principalmente listas muy grandes con muy pocos elementos a eliminar o necesitáramos si o si hacer esto in-place.

Para estos casos, podemos plantearnos realizar la eliminación in-place. En cualquier caso debemos intentar iterar una única vez sobre la lista. Una posibilidad es obtener los índices de los elementos a eliminar y hecho esto, con algo de aritmética podemos eliminar todos los elementos localizados en esos índices:

```
def eliminar_todos_los_items(items: set, lista: list) -> None:
    indices = [i  for i, e in enumerate(lista) if e in items]
    for i, indice in enumerate(indices):
        del lista[indice - i]
```

> Para Python < 3.5 eliminar la declaración de tipos de la función (son solo informativos): `def eliminar_todos_los_items(items, lista):`

Por ejemplo, para eliminar todos los 0 y 3:

> ```
> >>> l = [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 8, 1, 12, 0, 3, 7]
> >>> eliminar_todos_los_items({0, 3}, l)
> >>> l
> [1, 4, 8, 1, 12, 7]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Crea otra lista y úsala como acumulador:

```
a = [1,2,0,3,0]
b=[]

for i in a:
    if i!=0:
        b.append(i)
```

b dará como resultado: `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Otra manera podría ser con filter:

a = [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0]

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, a)))  #>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```