# Problema con .remove() python

Tags: python, lista

no entiendo por qué al realizar el print(i) se salta uno siempre que eliminó el anterior, espero me puedan ayudar gracias!

```
a=[[0.3, "p1"],[0.2, "p2"],[0.2, "p3"],[0.3, "p4"],[0.2, "p5"],[0.3, "p6"]]
for i in a:
    print(i)
    if i[0] == 0.3:
        a.remove(i)
```

me entrega lo siguiente:

```
[0.3, 'p1']
[0.2, 'p3']
[0.3, 'p4']
[0.3, 'p6']
```

se salta p2 y p5, luego:

```
print("ahora a es: ", a)
```

entrega:

```
ahora a es:  [[0.2, 'p2'], [0.2, 'p3'], [0.2, 'p5']]
```

Comment: Iterar sobre una lista (o cualquier iterable) y modificar su longitud mientras iteras es una idea muy mala... Mirate [Recorrer y eliminar todos los ceros de una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142216/15089)

Comment: @FJSevilla perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: En la respuesta de abulafia a la pregunta que enlazo lo explica muy bien, básicamente en tu primera iteración eliminas el primer item de la lista (`p1`), de forma que **`p2` pasa a ser el primero ahora**. En la siguiente iteración el iterador retorna el segundo elemento de la lista, que ahora es `p3`, consecuencia: `p2` nunca es iterado... Voy a marcar la pregunta como duplicada, pero si te surge cualquier duda comenta. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so].

Comment: @FJSevilla aah perfecto, clarísimo, gracias