# IndexError: list index out of range cuando se remueve item de array

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, condiciones

Tengo una función que lo que hace es remover un item de un array si este es igual a una palabra en especifico. Para ello el usuario ingresa una frase que luego es transformada en un array, la función itera sobre el array buscando la palabra (que puede estar en varias ocasiones).

Si la palabra solo esta una vez, todo funciona bien. Pero si la palabra está más de una vez en el array, da el error IndexError: list index out of range (Supongo que porque el array ha cambiado de tamaño)

```py
fraze=input("frase: ")
palabras=fraze.split(" ")

def borrar(palabras):
    for i in range(len(palabras)):
        if (palabras[i] == "la"):
            palabras.remove(palabras[i])
```

De antemano muchas gracias, ha de ser alguna bobada, pero no tengo mucha experiencia programando y solo lo hago por hobby.

Comment: Eliminar elementos de una lista mientras la estás recorriendo te puede llevar a resultados imprevistos. No lo hagas. En su  lugar construye otra lista inicialmente vacía a la que irás añadiendo las palabras que "sobrevivan" a la criba, y retorna esa nueva lista. Por ejemplo mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142218/7123)

Comment: En el momento que eliminas un elemento de la lista un índice deja de ser válido dado que la lista tiene un elemento menos. Hay que ser muy cuidadoso cundo se itera a la vez que se modifica el número de elementos en un iterable dado. En la pregunta marcada como duplicado tienes varias respuestas, la de abulafia y stevensonro eliminan los items creando una nueva lista con los elementos eliminados, la mía un poco menos "convencional" lo hace in-place. Si tienes alguna duda comenta. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so].