# Eliminar sublista dentro de una lista en función de uno de sus items

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Compañeros mi código funciona bien no tiene ningún error, en la "superlista" colección almaceno sublistas con información de cada usuario, pero mi duda es que cuando hayan muchos usuarios y cada usuario tenga mucha mas información como haría para eliminar a un usuario? porque si en cada sublista hubiera no 3 sino 7 elementos me tocaría hacer un for con 7 iteradores que recorra cada elemento de cada sublista lo cual no se vería bien

```
coleccion=[]

for a in range(3):
    nombre=input("\nDigite el nombre: ")
    apellido=input("Digite el apellido: ")
    dni=input("Digite el dni: ")
    coleccion.append([nombre,apellido,dni])


dni2=input("\nDigite el dni del cliente que desea elminar: ") #Variabla a comparar  

for nombre,apellido,dni in coleccion: #3 iteradores que recorran los 3 elementos que tiene cada sublista
    if dni2==dni: 
        coleccion.remove([nombre,apellido,dni]) #Borramos la sublista del cliente que su dni coincida con la variable dni2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero hay que entender que hace `list.remove`, básicamente **itera** la lista y elimina **solo el primer item** que encuentra que sea igual al pasado como argumento. Si no lo encuentra lanza una excepción `ValueError`.

Segundo, por norma general **debes evitar siempre iterar sobre una lista al mismo tiempo que agregas o eliminas items de la misma in-place**. Esto modifica la longitud del iterable, por tanto sus índices, y obtendrás resultados indeterminados al iterar (por ejemplo que el for se  salte ciertos items). Para más información mirate esta pregunta y sus respuestas:

- [Recorrer y eliminar todos los ceros de una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142216/15089)

Además de lo anterior, cuando haces:

```
for nombre,apellido,dni in coleccion:
    if dni2==dni: 
        coleccion.remove([nombre,apellido,dni])
```

iteras sobre la lista con el `for` y luego vuelves a iterar de forma implícita al hacer `coleccion.remove` lo que es ineficiente, más aún cuando creas una nueva lista `[nombre,apellido,dni]` para pasarla a `remove` a causa de desempaquetar la sublista en el `for`. Aunque no deberías hacerlo de esta forma nunca como ya se ha comentado.

En la respuestas a la pregunta anterior tienes varios métodos para eliminar todos los items de una lista que cumplan una característica, por ejemplo, en el caso de querer eliminar un item in-place en función solo de alguna característica, entonces puedes usar un `for` para filtrar los items y obtener los índices a eliminar, luego usa  `del` para eliminarlos:

```
a_eliminar = []
for index, usuario in enumerate(coleccion):
    if dni2 == usuario[2]: 
        a_eliminar.append()

for index in a_eliminar:
    del colección[index]
```

No obstante, **si sabes que solo tienes un item con ese DNI**, entonces si es seguro eliminar en el propio `for` que recorre la lista, **pero rompiéndolo inmediatamente al encontrar el elemento a eliminar**:

```
for index, usuario in enumerate(coleccion):
    if dni2 == usuario[2]: 
        del coleccion[index]
        print("Usuario con eliminado")
        break
    else:
        print("Usuario no encontrado")
```

---

Aunque no responde a tu pregunta, para estos casos, en los que tienes una característica que se presume única, como es el DNI, un diccionario suele ser mejor contenedor para tus datos. Un diccionario no permite repeticiones en sus claves, la cual puede ser el DNI. La mayor ventaja es que las búsquedas por la clave son mucho más simples y mucho más eficientes:

```
coleccion = {}

for _ in range(3):
    nombre = input("\nDigite el nombre: ")
    apellido = input("Digite el apellido: ")
    dni = input("Digite el dni: ")
    if dni in coleccion:
        res = input("Ya existe un usuario con ese DNI, desea reemplazarlo (S/N): ")
        if res.lower != "s":
            continue      
    coleccion[dni] = {"nombre": nombre, "apellido": apellido}


dni = input("\nIngrese el DNI a buscar: ")
usuario = coleccion.get(dni)
if usuario is None:
    print("Lo siento, el DNI no existe")
else:
    print(f'Encontrado usuario {usuario["nombre"]} {usuario["apellido"]} con DNI {dni}')

dni = input("\nDigite el dni del cliente que desea eliminar: ")
try:
    del coleccion[dni]
    print("Usuario eliminado")
except KeyError:
    print("Usuario no encontrado")
```