# Problema con listas en python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un problema quiero eliminar una sub-lista que cumpla unas ciertas características en este caso quiero borrar una sub-lista que su `dni` coincida con el `dni` que ingreso en la variable `dni_eliminar` y el código me funciona me elimina la sub-lista que tenga ese mismo `dni` pero también me da error, me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Usuario borrado
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ensayo.py", line 15, in <module>
    for b in range(len(usuarios[a])-1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Mi código:

```
usuarios=[] #Superlista que almacenara sublistas de cada usuario

for a in range(2):
    nombre=input("\nDigite el nombre: ")
    apellido=input("Digite el apellido: ")
    dni=input("Digite el dni: ")
    edad=input("Digite su edad: ")
    profesion=input("Digite su profesion: ")
    usuarios.append([nombre,apellido,dni,edad,profesion])  #Agregamos sublistas a la superlista


dni_eliminar=input("Ingrese el dni del usuario que desea eliminar: ")

for a in range(len(usuarios)): #Con los dos for recorro cada elemento de cada sublista
    for b in range(len(usuarios[a])): 
        if usuarios[a][b]==dni_eliminar: 
            del usuarios[a]
            print("Usuario borrado")
            break
else:
    print("Usuario no encontrado")
```

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta está relacionada directamente con:

- [Eliminar sublista dentro de una lista en función de uno de sus items](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/280480/15089) (Supongo que es la misma tarea académica)
- [Recorrer y eliminar todos los ceros de una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142216/recorrer-y-eliminar-todos-los-ceros-de-una-lista)

No obstante la causa real del fallo se debe a dos situaciones que se dan simultáneamente:

- Al eliminar un item de la lista, ésta pierde un elemento y con él un índice válido. Es decir, cuando se hace  `del usuarios[a]`, usuarios que antes tenia dos items pasa a tener uno. Por lo que el rango de índices calculado en el primer `for` con len(usuarios) ya no es válido, dado que `elementos[1]` ya no existe. Esta es la razón por la que se debe por lo general evitar iterar sobre un contenedor al mismo tiempo que se agregan o eliminan elementos. Ver segunda pregunta enlazada arriba.
- Posiblemente esto ya lo sabias, por lo de incluir el `break` en el segundo `for`. El problema es que **`break` solo rompe el ciclo al que pertenece,** en este caso, rompe el segundo `for`, pero no el principal. Al volver a iterar el primer `for`, intenta ejecutarse `for b in range(len(usuarios[a])):` y aquí tenemos el problema mencionado arriba, al ser `a=1`, `usuarios[1]` no es un indizado válido ya que la lista a pasado a tener un solo item.

Sin tocar tu código y repito, asumiendo que solo existe un usuario con ese DNI, la solución es romper ambos ciclos usando un `break` a nivel del primer loop controlado por una variable y un condicional:

```
buscando = True
for a in range(len(usuarios)):
    for b in range(len(usuarios[a])): 
        if usuarios[a][b] == dni_eliminar: 
            del usuarios[a]
            print("Usuario borrado")
            buscando  = False
            break
    if not buscando:
        break
```

Otra opción sería usar una función y hacer uso de `return`:

```
def eliminar_usuario_por_dni(usuarios, dni):
    for a in range(len(usuarios)):
        for b in range(len(usuarios[a])): 
            if usuarios[a][b] == dni_eliminar: 
                del usuarios[a]
                print("Usuario borrado")
                return
    else:
        print("Usuario no encontrado")

dni_eliminar = input("Ingrese el dni del usuario que desea eliminar: ")
eliminar_usuario_por_dni(usuarios, dni_eliminar)
```

No obstante, si conoces la posición del DNI en la lista, es más simple usar un `for in` con `enumerate` como se muestra en mi respuesta a la primera pregunta enlazada arriba, o en todo caso, si tienes o quieres usar indizado con `range`:

```
for i in range(len(usuarios)):
    if usuarios[i][2] == dni_eliminar: 
        del usuarios[i]
        print("Usuario borrado")
        break
    else:
        print("Usuario no encontrado")
```

con lo que nos evitamos el problema del `break` y el `for` principal.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, la forma en que lo haces, te complicas demasiado.
Lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera, menos código y mas legible:

```
usuarios=[] #Superlista que almacenara sublistas de cada usuario

for a in range(2):
    nombre=input("\nDigite el nombre: ")
    apellido=input("Digite el apellido: ")
    dni=input("Digite el dni: ")
    edad=input("Digite su edad: ")
    profesion=input("Digite su profesion: ")
    usuarios.append([nombre,apellido,dni,edad,profesion])  #Agregamos sublistas a la superlista


dni_eliminar=input("Ingrese el dni del usuario que desea eliminar: ")

# Eliminamos el usuario
for usuario in usuarios:
    if dni_eliminar in usuario: 
        usuarios.remove(usuario)
        print('Usuario borrado')
        break
```

También tendrías que solucionar el problema en caso que el `dni` ingresado no exista.

Otra solución mejor en mi opinión para hacerlo, seria con compresión de listas, de la siguiente manera:

```
usuarios = [usuario for usuario in usuarios if dni_eliminar not in usuario]
```

Es mejor y menos código, Y Quedaría así:

```
usuarios=[] #Superlista que almacenara sublistas de cada usuario

for a in range(2):
    nombre=input("\nDigite el nombre: ")
    apellido=input("Digite el apellido: ")
    dni=input("Digite el dni: ")
    edad=input("Digite su edad: ")
    profesion=input("Digite su profesion: ")
    usuarios.append([nombre,apellido,dni,edad,profesion])  #Agregamos sublistas a la superlista


dni_eliminar=input("Ingrese el dni del usuario que desea eliminar: ")

usuarios = [usuario for usuario in usuarios if dni_eliminar not in usuario]
print('Usuario borrado')
```

También aquí tu código estructurado de una manera mas limpia y legible:

```
users = []

for i in range(2):
    users.append([
        input("Digite el nombre: "),
        input("Digite el apellido: "),
        input("Digite el dni: "),
        input("Digite su edad: "),
        input("Digite su profesion: "),
    ])

dni = input("Ingrese el dni del usuario que desea eliminar: ")

users = [user for user in users if dni not in user]
print('Usuario borrado')
```