# list index out of range python

Tags: python

```
def capas(red): #red es un map
    listaAux = []
    for clave in red:
        for char in clave[2:len(red):2]:
            listaAux.append(char)
            listaAux.sort()
            for x in range(len(listaAux)):
                while x < len(listaAux):
                    if(listaAux[x]==listaAux[x+1]):
                        listaAux.pop(x)
                      

    return listaAux
```

El caso es que me sale "list index out of range" al intentar eliminar elementos de mi lista. Mi lista es tal que así: [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2...] , y no sé porqué motivo.

```
capas(red_1)

['0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '1',
 '1',
 '2',
 '2',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '5',
 '5',
 '5',
 '5',
 '5',
 '6',
 '6',
 '6',
 '6',
 '6',
 '7',
 '7',
 '7',
 '8',
 '8',]
```

el  mapa de entrada que voy convirtiendo a la lista anterior sería este:

```
red_1 = {"w_0_3": 1.0, "w_1_3": 1.0, "w_2_3": 1.0,
"w_0_4": 1.0, "w_1_4": 1.0, "w_2_4": 1.0,
"w_0_5": 1.0, "w_3_5": 1.0, "w_4_5": 1.0,
"w_0_6": 1.0, "w_3_6": 1.0, "w_4_6": 1.0,
"w_0_7": 1.0, "w_5_7": 1.0, "w_6_7": 1.0,
"w_0_8": 1.0, "w_5_8": 1.0, "w_6_8": 1.0}
```

Comment: Agrega la llamada que haces, mostrando la lista que estas pasando.

Comment: editada la pregunta con la informacion

Comment: No elimines elementos de una lista mientras la recorres. Mira por ejemplo esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142218/7123

Comment: Aparte del problema mencionado, supongo que  `clave[2:len(red):2]` debería ser en realidad `clave[2::2]` ¿no?

Comment: sí , eso es [2::2]

Comment: Si , pero lo de eliminar elemento de la lista mientras recorro , creo que no es el problema?

Comment: Ese también es un problema. Al eliminar elementos de una lista, ésta reduce su longitud, por lo que al final te saldrás de la misma (además de que los elementos se recolocan y podrías saltarte elementos, porque irían a parar a índices que ya has visitado)

Answer (score -1):

No se lo que hace el código, pero podemos analizarlo.

En su primera iteraciòn, `listaAux` está vacia y luego agregas un elemento:

```
listaAux.append(char)
```

Con eso, `listaAux` queda de largo 1.

Luego ejecutas estas tres lineas:

```
for x in range(len(listaAux)):
    while x < len(listaAux):
        if(listaAux[x]==listaAux[x+1]):
```

que es lo mismo que escribir:

```
for x in range(1):   # x = 0, o 1.
    while x < 1:     # x = 0
        if listaAux[0] == listaAux[1]:
```

Y no existe `listaAux[1]`. Sólo has agregado un elemento, `listaAux[0]`.

Ese es el problema. Habría que chequear los indices antes de hacer la operación.

Comment: La lista no está vacía , es la lista larga que he puesto antes ordenada de 0 a 8

Comment: El código muestra que `listaAux = []`, por lo tanto, la lista esta vacia. No veo donde adquiere los valores que mencionas.